# Why do I get errors with the RSForm! Pro Joomla! User Registration Plugin?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am able to install the User Registration Plugin but unable to use or configure it. I'm using 1.3.0 r36 with Joomla! 1.5.23. I keep getting the following errors:

Configuration Page:

1)

```
Warning: array_unshift() [function.array-unshift]: The first argument should be an array in /home/vertigom/public_html/home/plugins/system/rsfpregistration.php on line 583
```

2)

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vertigom/public_html/home/libraries/joomla/html/html/select.php on line 68
```

Manage Forms Page:
"Table RSForm_Registration not supported. File not found."

I even tried the plugin with 1.4.0 but to no avail. Any solutions?

Comment: Probably a question better suited for that product's support forum, mailing list, or author

Comment: Thanks Pekka for the swift reply. I have tried posting on their forum & going through support but I have not got any answers so far.

Comment: Turns out some files were missing. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some files were missing. I reinstalled & now it works.